# world coordinates vector to image coordinates

Tags: opencv, math, 3d, computer-vision, geometry

I have a 3d world coordinates system and corresponding translation vector, rotation matrix and camera matrix.
I can project any of my points to the image plane using cv2.projectPoints.
my question is if I can project a vector?
lets look on a drawing:
[image]

for context, the circle is an eyeball located on an head, and I can project points 1,2 to the image plane using cv2.projectPoints.
Is there a way to project the vector 1->2 to the image plane?
it would be the direction the eye is looking.
we can suppose that the distance between the eye and the camera is predefined, and static.

I don't really sure if projection is the right term. will appreciate any pointers to the right direction

Comment: help me clarify this: are you trying to express this direction vector in the 2d -  image domain ?   -> in this case if you already projected point1 and point2 to this image plane the direction vector would just be the  (point2 - point1)

Comment: but somehow i guess this is not what your're asking here...

Comment: yes, you can project vectors. if you have coordinates like (x,y,1) or (x,y,z,1) for points, then you need (x,y,0) or (x,y,z,0) for vectors. that's how calculations with vanishing points work. -- I'm not awake enough yet to see if that's similar enough to a line-plane intersection

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is using simple line-plane intersection.
you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection) for more Information.